# Why are ether delta gas prices so high as of recently?

Tags: gas, gas-limit, gas-price, gas-estimate, etherdelta

My question is about why the gas price and gas limit are so high as of lately on ether delta?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there's higher activity on the Ethereum network hence the estimated gas prices are higher since it's determined by the x latest blocks median gas price. The gas limit is determined by how many computational steps are required in the smart contract method you're calling.